# Sort 2d array by first element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a 2d array like so:

```
myArray = [ [20,6], [12,6], [17,6], [2,6], [11,5], [18,5], [7,4], [4,4] ];
```

I wish to sort it by first index values - [2,6] should come before [12,6], [16,6]... [4,4] before [7,4] in that order... to obtain:

```
sortedArray = [ [2,6], [12,6], [17,6], [20,6], [11,5], [18,5], [4,4], [7,4] ];
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate but you can do it like this.. `myArray.sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0])`

Comment: @HalilÇakar That doesn't work.

Comment: If we sort it by first value as you mentioned, your expected output is wrong then.

Comment: @HalilÇakar `a[0] - b[0]` rather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to respect the sorting of the second item of each array:

1. sort by index `1` descending,
2. sort by index `0` ascending.

```js
const array = [[20, 6], [12, 6], [17, 6], [2, 6], [11, 5], [18, 5], [7, 4], [4, 4]];

array.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1] || a[0] - b[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide sort with a comparison function.

```
myArray.sort(function(x,y){
    return x[0] - y[0];
});
```

Here's the reference for sort function - [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the first element like this.

```js
const myArray = [ [20,6], [12,6], [17,6], [2,6], [11,5], [18,5], [7,4], [4,4] ];

let ans = myArray.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a[0] - b[0]
})

console.log(ans)
```