# Reassignment of variable value causing trouble within array (vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**Context:** A program I'm writing generates an array that contains arrays. I would like to sort the array according to the value of `arrayElement[0]` (i.e. the first value within each sub-array).

In the example below, I take the `arrayElement[0]` values, put them into a separate array (`tempSortArray`) and sort them. Then I run a nested loop to take items from the original `foo` array and put them, in order, into the `finalFooArray`.

**Actual problem:** In case there are several array items with the same `arrayElement[0]` value, I have added `y[0] = false` *after* adding `y` to the `finalFooArray`. This ought to prevent the code from constantly adding the same elements over and over.

However, the resultant array is this: `false,[object Object],[object Object],false,[object Object],[object Object],false,[object Object],[object Object]`, i.e. the `y[0] = false` somehow makes its way into the array, even though I changed the value *after* putting the value into the array.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

```
var foo = [
    [28888888, {x: 12,y: 3},{x: 1,y: 45678}],
    [78, {x: 54,y: 3}, {x: 3,y: 3}],
    [456, {x: 1,y: 76543}, {x: 765432,y: 7}]
];
let tempSortArray = [];
let finalFooArray = [];
foo.forEach((item) => {
    tempSortArray.push(item[0]);
});
tempSortArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
});
   
for (let x of tempSortArray) {
    for (let y of foo) {
        if (x == y[0]) {
            finalFooArray.push(y);
            y[0] = false; // Change the value of y[0] just in case there are several items with the same y[0] value
        }
    }
}
console.log(`The sorted array goes like this: ${finalFooArray}`);
```

Comment: also [How to sort 2 dimensional array by column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value) and [Sort 2d array by first element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619436/sort-2d-array-by-first-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just sort by the first item of each array?

```js
var foo = [
    [28888888, {x: 12,y: 3},{x: 1,y: 45678}],
    [78, {x: 54,y: 3}, {x: 3,y: 3}],
    [456, {x: 1,y: 76543}, {x: 765432,y: 7}]
];


console.log(foo.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
  if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
  return 0
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary array; just directly sort the array, returning the difference between the first elements in the callback.

```js
var foo = [
    [28888888, {x: 12,y: 3},{x: 1,y: 45678}],
    [78, {x: 54,y: 3}, {x: 3,y: 3}],
    [456, {x: 1,y: 76543}, {x: 765432,y: 7}]
];
foo.sort((a, b)=>a[0] - b[0]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));
```